# Changing Dictionary Key

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, datatable

I am getting data from data table and convert it into json like this:

```
public object DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                dict.Add(col.ColumnName,row[col]);
            }
            list.Add(dict);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return serializer.Serialize(list);
    }
```

But while iterating through JSON data , this method is giving key names as column1,column2...(as datatable don't have any column name) 
I want the column names should be something like 1,2...
How can I achieve this using above method ?

Comment: You can try this  dict.Add((col.Ordinal+1).ToString(),row[col])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
dict.Add(col.ColumnName,row[col]);
```

to

```
var keyName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(col.ColumnName) 
    ? col.Ordinal + 1 
    : col.ColumnName;
dict.Add(keyName, row[col]);
```

When you have a column name this will be taken and we you don't have one you will take the index + 1 of the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can build in a Counter

```
public object DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                dict.Add(counter.ToString(),row[col]);
                counter++;
            }
            list.Add(dict);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return serializer.Serialize(list);
    }
```

But keep in mind: double keynames are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The Ordinal property of the DataColumn object will give you the position of the column, so you can tweak your code to use this.

```
public object DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                dict.Add((col.Ordinal+1).ToString(),row[col]) ;
            }
            list.Add(dict);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return serializer.Serialize(list);
    }
```